# GWT Compile Error - Restlet related?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, restlet

The XXX are just names that I need to keep confidential.

```
Compiling module com.XXX.XXX.XXX_Test
   Validating newly compiled units
      Ignored 12 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Scanning for additional dependencies: file:/D:/Eclipse/Indigo/Workspace/XXX%20Test/src/com/XXX/XXX/client/Restlet.java
      Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.wai.XXX.client.proxy.DonglesProxy'
         Rebinding com.XXX.XXX.client.proxy.DonglesProxy
            Checking rule <generate-with class='org.restlet.rebind.ClientProxyGenerator'/>
               [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/D:/Eclipse/Indigo/Workspace/XXX%20Test/src/com/XXX/XXX/client/proxy/DonglesProxy.java'
                  [ERROR] Line 11: No source code is available for type org.restlet.resource.ClientProxy; did you forget to inherit a required module?
               [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.XXX.XXX.client.proxy.DonglesProxy'
                  [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
                  [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

Here is what the console tells me when I try to do a GWT Compile on my project. What I don't understand that I've included the 'org.restlet.jar' into the buildpath of the project and have the following imports in the DonglesProxy source code:

```
import org.restlet.resource.ClientProxy;
import org.restlet.resource.Put;
```

Anyone any ideas?

I'm new to Java and the whole Web Application process so my knowledge is a bit lacking. This is actually someone else's project that has been left unfinished so I'm trying to debug/understand someone else code whilst learning as I go along...nightmare :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers
Kev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use :

- import org.restlet.**client**.resource.ClientProxy;
- import org.restlet.**client**.resource.Get;
- import org.restlet.**client**.resource.Post;
- import org.restlet.**client**.resource.Result;

to define the proxies; Take notice of the **"client"** part;

The referenced imports must be part of the GWT distribution;

Comment: Hi Koma, Thanks for getting back to me. I tried using the org.restlet.client.resource.xxx but my project no longer builds and generates this error.

Comment: what error ? you need <inherits name="org.restlet.Restlet" /> in your module, add the GWT version of restlet to your classpath, and probably the J2EE version on the server's classpath for implementing the serverside;

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I managed to solve the GWT compile but have run into another issue. Can you tell me the difference between Deploying the App Engine and Run as Web Application?

Comment: GAE deploy = send to google and run on their infrastructure == production, Run as webapp = local development; but you shouldn't ask additional questions in comments,but accept and reopen a new one.

Comment: Cool again new to the forum, will post up a new question next time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to your projects xml file. That is to com.XXX.XXX.XXX_Test.gwt.xml or something like that.
You have to add this line there,

```
<inherits name='org.restlet.whateverClass.xmlfilename />'
```

This means you are pointing to the xml file named xmlfilename.xml at the path org.restlet.whteverclass

So say for example if i am using sencha ui libraries jar, I will add,

```
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />
```

So here there will should be a xml file called GXT.xml at the path 'com.sencha.gxt.ui'

Comment: It isn't irrelevan, this is the soution, he has to add inherits in his gwt.xml, its not enough if he just has it in his classpath

Comment: the class mentionned in the compile error is simply the wrong one "org.restlet.resource.ClientProxy"; there is no module that will ever include this class;

Comment: but sorry if i was sounding brutal, i realise now